# get the wrong answer for divide in Java

Tags: java

I'm a newbie in Java. this is a part of my program. i should get a 0.65 as a result but java result is 0.0. how to solve it?

```
    double xinc;
    int dx = 190;
    int len = 290;
    xinc = dx/len;
    System.out.println(xinc);
```

Comment: Read up on int division. Not my down-vote, but your Google skills need a little work.

Answer (score 2):

```
int/int = int
```

You have to make `dx` and `len` as `double` in order to get a `double` result else you can also type cast `dx` and `len` to `double`.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
xinc = (double)dx/len;
```

Also, before posting, Google.

> int / int = int
>   int / double = double
>   double / int = double